# Visualizing a scenario where wave vector's direction is different from Poynting vector's one

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, vectors, poynting-vector

Can someone help me visualize how the direction of the wave vector can be different from the one of the poynting vector in a scenario like a lossy medium? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: If anything they do not have the same dimensions.  Do you mean a situation where they do not point in the same direction?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes!

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354728/36194 and answers therein.

Comment: Why did you add to your question the detail of a lossy medium? Is it really relevant to you? I think that it would be much simpler to consider the case of an evanescent wave at the flat interface between two semi-infinite, linear, loss-less and homogeneous media. In this case, it is possible to show that the poynting vector will be parallel to the interface, while the wave vector will have a purely imaginary component perpendicular to it. IMO, this is maybe the best simple example for testing your understanding of all this stuff.

Comment: @JackI I thought a lossy medium would be the simplest scenario. Since that's not the case, I'll check out your scenario